# class variable is undefined after subscribing observable in lifecycle hook

Tags: typescript, angular, undefined

I try to set a variable (json object) in my component class. ngOnInit subscribing an observable service and set the component variable. 
When I try to access this variable with dot notation in components template, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'count_runs' of undefined

The observable has a type annotation (avgTime Interface).

avg-time.ts

```
export interface AvgTime {
  avg_runtime_millis: number;
  count_runs: number;
}
```

stats.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AvgTime } from './avg-time';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class StatsService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  private _avgTimeUrl = 'http://localhost:3002/api/reservation/avgTime';

  getAvgTime() : Observable<AvgTime> {
    return this._http.get(this._avgTimeUrl)
               .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

avg-time.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AvgTime } from './avg-time';
import { StatsService } from './stats.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'avg-time',
  template: `
    <h1>AvgTimeComponent</h1>
    {{avgTime.count_runs}}
  `,
  providers: [StatsService]
})
export class AvgTimeComponent implements OnInit {
  avgTime: AvgTime;

  constructor(private _statsService: StatsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._statsService.getAvgTime()
        .subscribe(avgTime => this.avgTime = avgTime);
  }
}
```

It is also not working when I fake the service response in ngOnInit like:

avg-time.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._statsService.getAvgTime()
        .subscribe(avgTime => {
          this.avgTime = {
            avg_runtime_millis: 150,
            count_runs: 20
          };
        });
  }
```

The return of my stats.service.ts from backend is:

```
[{"AVG_RUNTIME_MILLIS":55,"COUNT_RUNS":5400}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leverage the Elvis operator:

```
{{avgTime?.count_runs}}
```

since avgTime is set asynchronously and is undefined at first...

Comment: this is working, but I try to understand the problem. Is this caused by observables, that they dont have to return something? Should I use elvis operator in the interface? Are promises solving this problem?

Comment: It's because `avgTime` isn't undefined before you receive the data from the observable (it would be the same with a promise). Angular2 tries to evaluate the expression when the component is loaded and at this moment the value isn't received. So when it tries to get the `count_runs` property, there is an error. The Elvis operator prevents from this. If the object is undefined, no error will be thrown.

Comment: so using elvis operator in this case is state of the art?